# Why is my mutable linked list slower than the immutable variant?

Tags: haskell, optimization, linked-list

I have a use case where I need a structure that has a constant time insertion and then can be iterated from oldest to newest. Basically a queue. The difference is that the insertion and iteration happen in separate steps to a simple list is ALMOST good enough. I just need to do one reverse at the end.
This reverse is what I'm trying to get rid off.

I've set out to implement this myself inside the `ST` monad.
The resulting performance is 4 times slower. I'll include all of the relevant code (it's self contained) and the function I'm using to benchmark it. You can compile it yourself provided you install the `timeit` package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
module LinkedListSpecial where

import Prelude hiding (mapM_)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import Data.Foldable (mapM_, foldlM, forM_)
import System.TimeIt

data LLN s a = Stub (STRef s (Maybe (LLN s a)))
             | LLN a (STRef s (Maybe (LLN s a)))

getRef :: LLN s a -> STRef s (Maybe (LLN s a))
getRef (Stub ref)  = ref
getRef (LLN _ ref) = ref

emptyNode :: ST s (LLN s a)
emptyNode = fmap Stub (newSTRef Nothing)

makeNode :: a -> ST s (LLN s a)
makeNode x = fmap (LLN x) $! newSTRef Nothing

append :: LLN s a -> a -> ST s (LLN s a)
append (getRef -> ref) x = do
    new <- makeNode x
    writeSTRef ref (Just new)
    return new

iter :: (a -> ST s ()) -> LLN s a -> ST s ()
iter f (Stub ref) = do
    next <- readSTRef ref
    mapM_ (iter f) next
iter f (LLN x ref) = do
    f x
    next <- readSTRef ref
    mapM_ (iter f) next

fromList :: [a] -> ST s (LLN s a, LLN s a)
fromList xs = do
    f <- emptyNode
    l <- foldlM append f xs
    return (f, l)

test :: IO ()
test = do
    let seedList = [1..1000000]
    print "Normal list"
    timeIt $ print $ runST $ do
        ref <- newSTRef []
        forM_ seedList (\i -> modifySTRef' ref (i :))
        list <- readSTRef ref
        return (sum list :: Integer)
    print "Linked list"
    timeIt $ print $ runST $ do
        (listBegin, _) <- fromList seedList
        s <- newSTRef (0 :: Integer)
        iter (\i -> modifySTRef' s (+ i)) listBegin
        readSTRef s
```

I would appreciate it if someone more skilled in optimization would tell me what can be improved.

Edit:
The performance drop is less drastic when running compiled code, but my list is still about twice as slow.

Comment: Maybe just use a Sequence? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html

Comment: I guess the obvious first question is, "what are you doing that the amortized-O(1) cost of list reversal isn't working out for you?" Because lists are already pretty fast and can get even faster for this sort of application if you make them spine-strict; moreover you can't asymptotically get faster than them for this purpose so you're chasing a better multiplicative constant -- and that only comes when you simplify the code that actually gets run by the CPU, reduce memory allocations, etc.

Comment: I did try them out and they were even slower.

Comment: @ChrisDrost I'm aware of that and that's exactly what I want to do! Hopefully someone can show me how. What I'm doing in the `test` function is actually more or less what's happening in my original application. I'm hesitant to get into more details than needed because, despite peoples best intentions, my original desires will get overlooked and I'll just get the "here's a package that already does that" answers.

Comment: @ChrisDrost What I'm looking for here is a 2 times speed increase over what I'm doing with the regular list. If you can achieve that WITH the regular list, I would also accept that answer.

Comment: Have you tried using a difference list?

Comment: @icktoofay I didn't. I'll see if it makes a _difference_ (ehehehehe)

Comment: @icktoofay It did! This does solve my original problem and I'll be sure to check out how DLists are done. The question still stands and I would love to get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple reason is that the tradeoffs GHC's runtime system (especially the garbage collector) makes are designed to make immutable data as fast as possible, at the expense of speed in code that mutates cells pointing to boxed values.  In particular, the GC system makes lots of optimizations that assume values are mutated at most once (lazy evaluation).  When those conditions aren't true, it adds a bunch of overhead because it has to work around those optimizations.

As for solving it, it seems someone else mentioned difference lists, and they do indeed work.  No need to use the package, though.  It's a sufficiently simple data type that you might as well inline your uses of it, unless you need the instances the package provides.

The basic idea is that you don't work with lists, you work with functions instead.

```
nil :: [a] -> [a]
nil = id

snoc :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
snoc x f = f . (x :)

toList :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a]
toList f = f []
```

This gives you really good performance in the use case where you perform a bunch of `snoc` operations, followed by converting it to a list a single time.  It's *really* bad when your pattern is `snoc` a single element, traverse, repeat.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, though I wouldn't mind a bit of elaboration on how I could make my current method better. I realize trade offs have to be made but isn't the whole point of having special cases that allow mutation so that you can write algorithms that perform better with it? Is mutation really just outright slow in GHC? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: While it is true that there are cases where a mutable data structure can perform better than an immutable one, yours doesn't seem to be one of them. If you haven't, I recommend that you take a look at Okasaki's Purely Functional Data Structures book (http://www.amazon.com/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504) or just his paper on Queues and dQueues (http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf).

Comment: @LukaHorvat First, the slowness mostly is due to boxed values with the garbage collector. If your mutable cell contains only unboxed values, there is no slowness. Second, despite that, mutability can be a win even with boxed values in the cases where it can shave an asymptotic factor of O(log n) off your algorithm.

Comment: @Carl So the case where my mutable values are boxed and I'm trying to reduce the multiplicative constant is where I'm stuck with that tradeoff?

Comment: @LukaHorvat Well, that's where you're going to be paying most for the tradeoffs, yes.